# How to send requests with JSON in unit tests

Tags: python, json, flask, python-unittest

I have code within a Flask application that uses JSONs in the request, and I can get the JSON object like so:

```
Request = request.get_json()
```

This has been working fine, however I am trying to create unit tests using Python's unittest module and I'm having difficulty finding a way to send a JSON with the request.

```
response=self.app.post('/test_function', 
                       data=json.dumps(dict(foo = 'bar')))
```

This gives me:

```
>>> request.get_data()
'{"foo": "bar"}'
>>> request.get_json()
None
```

Flask seems to have a JSON argument where you can set json=dict(foo='bar') within the post request, but I don't know how to do that with the unittest module.

Comment: What does the `request.data` contains? Often when json parsing fails due to wrong input, it fails silently and return `None` thus the raw input data may not be json.

Comment: >>> request.get_data()
'{"foo": "bar"}'
>>> request.get_json()
None

I'm not quite sure how flask's request works, but it seems to separate data and json, and I can't figure out how to send information to the json rather than the data, if that makes any sense.

Comment: i think it's the content type headers, try to set them to appliacation/json. also the force parameter is helpful but you probably don't want to go there just to make unittests pass, better to change mime

Answer (score 223, accepted):

Changing the post to

```
response=self.app.post('/test_function', 
                       data=json.dumps(dict(foo='bar')),
                       content_type='application/json')
```

fixed it.

Thanks to user3012759.

Comment: was wrecking my head around with this. Don't understand why you have to dump the data when you're already specifying the `application/json` content type.

Comment: I believe it's because everything you send in a post has to be a string.

Comment: Amazing this isn't in the docs, because flask's test_client has no API docs!

Comment: How to get data from response?

Comment: @variable, with a response from a `post`  request like `resp = client.post('/my/endpoint/',json=my_json_data)` you can access the data as bytes with `resp.data`.

Comment: be careful: using a call with the `json` instead of `data` argument (for example) = {"i": 3, "j": 5, "dx": 7, "m": 8} you risk of mixing keys. Order is sometimes important.

Answer (score 61):

Since Flask 1.0 release `flask.testing.FlaskClient` methods accepts `json` argument and `Response.get_json` method added, see [pull request](https://github.com/pallets/flask/pull/2358/files#diff-e77c5e10ff5f713fa04a6b0e61a1837cR267)

```py
    with app.test_client() as c:
        rv = c.post('/api/auth', json={
            'username': 'flask', 'password': 'secret'
        })
        json_data = rv.get_json()
```

For Flask 0.x compatibility you may use receipt below:

```py
    from flask import Flask, Response as BaseResponse, json
    from flask.testing import FlaskClient
    
    
    class Response(BaseResponse):
        def get_json(self):
            return json.loads(self.data)
    
    
    class TestClient(FlaskClient):
        def open(self, *args, **kwargs):
            if 'json' in kwargs:
                kwargs['data'] = json.dumps(kwargs.pop('json'))
                kwargs['content_type'] = 'application/json'
            return super(TestClient, self).open(*args, **kwargs)
    

    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.response_class = Response
    app.test_client_class = TestClient
    app.testing = True
```

Comment: And don't forget that the json argument must be a `dict` not a JSON string!

Comment: With this answer **there is no need** to create a custom client overwriting the `post` method to use JSON (checked in Flask 2.0.2)