# Flask AssertionError: 400 != 201

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest

I am trying to write a test case for my post end point, but I seriously do not know what I am doing wrong.

`views.py`

The user can post a product by typing the `name`, the `price` and `category` I have hard coded:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

products = [] 


class Product(Resource):

    def post(self, name):
        if next(filter(lambda x: x['name'] == name, products), None):
            return {'message':
                    "A product with name '{}' already exists."
                    .format(name)}, 400  
        data = request.get_json()
        product = {'id': len(products) + 1,
                   'name': name, 'price': data['price'],
                   'category': data['category']}
        products.append(product)
        return product, 201
```

When I run it I get the JSON data with a 201 OK response.

```
{
    "price": 50,
    "category": "stationery",
    "name": "pencil",
    "id": 2
}
```

But when I test it:

`test_product.py`

```
import unittest
import json
from app import create_app


class ProductTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    """This is the class for product test cases"""

    def setUp(self):
        self.app = create_app('testing')
        self.client = self.app.test_client

def test_to_add_product(self):
    """Test method to add product"""
     """Is this how the json payload is passed"""
    add_product = self.client().post('/api/v1/product/pencil', 
        data={
        "price": 50,
        "name": "pencil",
        "category": "stationery"
   },
        content_type='application/json')
    self.assertEqual(add_product.status_code, 201)
```

I get the following error:

```
E       AssertionError: 400 != 201

app/tests/v1/test_product.py:22: AssertionError
```

What does this mean, and how can I fix it?

**EDIT**

folowing this answer,[How to send requests with JSONs in unit tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28836893/how-to-send-requests-with-jsons-in-unit-tests), this worked for me:

```
def test_to_add_product(self):
    """Test method to add product"""
    add_product = self.client().post('/api/v1/product/pencil',
                                     data=json.dumps(
                                         dict(category='category',
                                              price='price')),
                                     content_type='application/json')
    self.assertEqual(add_product.status_code, 201)
```

Comment: If you are specifying content_type as json dont you need to pass the payload?

Answer (score 0):

[HTTP 400](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/400) means "bad request". It indicates that the request you're sending to your API endpoint is somehow invalid.

I don't see where you're passing any JSON data to your endpoint in your test. If JSON data is required (it appears to be since you have `data = request.get_json()` in your code) that would explain the bad request response.

If you include a valid JSON payload in your test you should see the response you expect.